# Вырезка строк Java

Tags: java

Имеется переменная типа String "daily - ежедневный".
Нужно вывести сначала "daily", а потом "ежедневный"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы как пробовали делать?

Делайте через `"daily - ежедневный".split("-");`

Comment: Дабы результат не содержал лишние пробелы нужно или поправить параметр на ‘ - ‘ или применить trim.